# Retrofit 1.9.0 contains which version of GSON?

Tags: retrofit

Which GSON version does Retrofit 1.9.0 contain? I'm having few issues with GSON while deserialising values (when they are null). So before i can start debugging, i just wanted to know about the GSON version.

Answer (score 0):

`Retrofit` 1.9.0 comes with `Gson` of version 2.3.1. you can get the source code of retorift 1.9.0 [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/releases/tag/parent-1.9.0). go through the source code and you can see the `Gson` version used.

you can find this in the maven file.

```
<gson.version>2.3.1</gson.version>
```

hope it helps